# is there a classical lie group acting transitively on a corona

Tags: complex-analysis, lie-groups

the title is quite self-explaining. Let's take a corona $\{z\in\mathbb{C},r<\mid z\mid<R\}$, for two strictly positive reals $r,R$. I am looking for a "classical" lie group that acts holomorphically transitively on the corona. And if not, a non classical will do the stuff;)

I thought of a subgroup of the isometries of the unit disk in the poincaré model, but I think there can not be any of this sort.

Comment: Is $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ classical?

Comment: Or do you want a complex Lie group and a holomorphic action?

Comment: The usual English word for that set is _annulus_, not corona.

Comment: @DanielFischer oops sorry indeed I need a homomorphically action. I updated my post

Comment: @JackLee thank you you're right ! Nevertheless, I just borrowed the word from corona problem ;)

Comment: In that case … the automorphism group of annuli is rather small. It only acts transitively if $r = 0$ and $R = +\infty$.

Comment: ok thanks you @DanielFischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a continuous action, the answer is yes: $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}=\mathrm{GL}(1,\mathbb{C})$ is a classical Lie group which acts transitively on itself by multiplication. Now use that $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:r<|z|<R\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

For a holomorphic action, the answer is no: If $f$ is a biholomorphism of the annuli, then either $|f(z)|=|z|$ for all $z$ or $|f(z)|=Rr/|z|$ for all $z$ (assuming $0<r,R<\infty$) (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324881/automorphism-group-of-annulus)). Hence, no holomorphic action can be transitive.

Comment: oops I have just updated my post. I need a holomorphic action