# Self-maps of the open annulus

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{A} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ be the open annulus. I'm interested in maps $f: \mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{A}$ and how they behave near the boundary components, namely the origin and the unit circle.

Assuming $f$ is a biholomorphism, according to Riemann's theorem, the origin becomes a removable singularity. This allows us to holomorphically extend $f$ to an automorphism $\tilde{f}$ of the unit disk, satisfying $\tilde{f}(0) = 0$. The behavior of such automorphisms near the unit circle is well-studied.

Now, let's consider the case where we forget about the complex structure and assume $f$ is merely a homeomorphism. I came across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324881/automorphism-group-of-annulus), where the answer suggests that if there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to the origin, then the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ would converge either to the origin or to the boundary. However, I am unsure about the details of the proof provided in the post. Could someone confirm if my understanding of the statement is correct and, if so, provide further explanation of the proof?

Comment: The proof in the post you cite doesn't make much sense to me. When you just consider the topology, your annulus is just a homeomorph of $(0, 1) \times S^1$ and there is no well-defined notion of "boundary component". E.g., if you take the one-point compactification, the "boundary" comprises a single point, $\infty$ say, and a sequence could oscillate wildly in the complex plane from being near the origin and being near the unit circle while still converging to $\infty$.

Comment: ... that being said, a homeomorphism $f$ from $A = (0, 1) \times S^1$ to itself cannot oscillate wildly: it must map $\{1/2\} \times S^1$ to a homeomorph of $S^1$ inside $A$, whose removal separates $A$ into two connected components both of which are homeomorphic to $A$ under a map you can define using $f$.

Comment: Do you know about ends of topological spaces?

Comment: @RobArthan Is this a consequence of the Jordan Curve Theorem?

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike Not really. Can you say something more about it?

Comment: While the Jordan Curve Theorem proves that arbitrary simple closed curves disconnect the plane, $\{1/2\}\times S^1$ is a very specific curve, for which the proof is far easier. That the image is a homeomorph of $S^1$ which disconnects $A$ into two connected components then follows from $f$ being a homeomorphism. So while you could resort to Jordan's theorem to prove it, it isn't necessary.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: thanks for your reply to Yoona's comment. I've been on vacation. I hope your comment fixed it for Yoona.